# Just when I thought my site was working right, it screws up in IE7

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I thought I'd done quite well, my site passed XHTML1.0 strict validation *and* worked flawlessly in IE6 as well as looking fine in IE8 & Chrome. I glibly thought that it it worked in IE6 & 8, IE7 was bound to be OK. But on checking I see one of my  has a scrollbar in IE7, the  seems about 200% as wide as it should be... the content is fine but you can scroll the whole . 2 separate pages have this issue, a 3rd does not, even though all pages use the same layout template - the main difference on the 2 that break is a floated div.

Are there known issues specifically in this area (floating) with IE7?

**edit:** [here's the live site](http://www.jdxsolutions.com), please be kind :).

**update:** tested in FF3 and it works there fine too. So Chrome, FF, IE8 and even IE6 all work flawlessly, but IE7 has some nasties.
**update:** IE8 compatibility mode also introduces the exact same behavior.

Comment: Please embarrass yourself ;) I would like to see a (test)website that works in IE6 and IE8 but not in IE7. I would imagine that it has to do something with the mode in which IE7 runs (to quirk or not to quirk).

Comment: well it would help if you posted the link so we can check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the width of your pageContent div using em's or px. You may have to enter in a specific css rule for IE7 (I believe its * + html {css rule}. From looking at the markup it seems no width property has been set.

Alternatively a quick fix would be to add a meta tag to force the page to always render in IE8 mode:

You can find more on this here:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/introducing-ieemulateie7)

Hope that helps

Comment: I can't force it to run in IE8 mode on IE7! About the width thing, which element do you refer to? The _main_ <div> has an explicit width of 800px set IIRC, is that not sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of fiddling I was able to find a solution by adding the following

```
html {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

I'm actually not sure what exactly caused the problem in the first place, but good luck to you with future IE debugging!